# < ajaxToolkit:TabPanel - would like to set "focus" on a different tab

Tags: asp.net, tabpanel

i have a < ajaxToolkit:TabPanel
initially when the page loads, the first tab is "open" ("focused on")

can i do something (preferably server side) so my second tab would be the "default" selected tab?

Answer (score 1):

Set the TabPanel's ActiveTabIndex to 1 in your Page.Load handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        TabPanel1.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
}
```

You can also set it in the markup: `<aspToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1">...</aspToolkit:TabPanel>`